# DDL exported by oracle database export puts create view before create table

Tags: database, export, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-dump

Using Oracle SQL Developer, I want to export databases to SQL scripts using the **"Tools"** > **"Database Export"** menu entry. I selected all the DDL entry to export. The problem now is the SQL file generated will have sections in order like DROP TABLE/VIEW, CREATE VIEW, CREATE TABLE, INSERT DATA.

It does not make sense to CREATE VIEW from table that has not been created yet. Is there any explanation for this? I did try to import the exported database from the dump file and it won't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer are you using? 4.1 doesn't do that, and I don't recall version 3.x doing it. Recent versions (at least) also have a 'add force to views' which might work around the issue - the view would be created as invalid, but after the table is created would recompile successfully.